# What is the difference between can and could in 'Can/could you please explain this to me?'

Tags: word-choice, difference, modal-verbs

> Can you please explain this to me?

> Could you please explain this to me?

I am unable to figure out which to use which situation. I did google, and some posts say they are both the same, even if the second one is more formal. Other posts say *could* is the past tense of *can*, but in the above example, I don't think *could* is used as past tense of *can*.

What is correct way to use these words?

Comment: English modal verbs have to do a lot of work, so they are very hard to pin down. This, however, is a fairly simple one. In this particular context, where *can* or *could* is used merely to ask for help, there is **no difference** at all. Any individual might have his or her own preference in various situations, so there are personal differences. Many grammarians think there *should* be a universal difference and wish there *were* a universal difference. But in actual use, there isn't: both will be understood as a polite request for help.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The quick answer: In most contexts, these two words are effectively synonyms, especially when discussing possibility, e.g. "(Can/Could) you [perform some action]?".

Longer answer:

There is a somewhat subtle difference in these two phrases that becomes a lot less subtle in different contexts. Let's take the words one at a time:

- **Can** deals with actual, literal *ability* to perform an action. When you ask if someone *can* explain something, you are literally asking whether they are capable of explaining it. **Edit:** It is important to note that, as @J.R. has pointed out, this is by no means the only use (or even the most common use) of the word *can* or the phrase *can you ...*. This construction is often abused to mean effectively the same thing as *could you...*, i.e. *would you be willing to...*, etc.
- **Could** deals with the *possibility* of performing an action. It is definitely a subtle difference, but basically, when you discuss *possibility*, you generally are aware of their *ability* to do it but are tentative about their willingness or availability to perform the action. This is by no means an exact definition.

It is also worth noting that the word *could* is actually the past tense of *can*. In English, using the past tense form of a word in this way is often meant to indicate tentativeness.

> I wanted to talk with you.
>   I wondered if you would be available this afternoon.
>   I thought it might a good idea.

Comment: +1 Exactly. But *can you **please*** transforms it from an inquiry into capability to a request for help.

Comment: **Can** _deals with actual, literal ability to perform an action. When you ask if someone can explain something, you are literally asking whether they are capable of explaining it._ I agree with this, but I think it's worth mentioning that many native speakers are careless about how they use this word, to the point where the word _can_ often gets stretched to mean other things, as in, "Can I go outside?" or, "Can I tell you a secret?"

Comment: @J.R.Absolutely. I'll edit to reflect this.

Comment: +1 for the past tense note.  Except, I'm not sure about the tentativeness qualification:  "Can you (eg open the safe), or can't you?" (present) directly translates to: "Could you open the safe or couldn't you" (past).

Comment: @mcalex As with most "rules" in English, this is (as mentioned) a *most of the time* or *often* or *sometimes* kind of thing. Of course it isn't tentative every time you use a past tense verb, but it *often* is.

Comment: Negation and tenses muddle these up even more. I think a post fully explaining the technical and practical subtleties of "can" vs. "can't" vs. "could" vs. "couldn't" would be essay-length.

Answer (score 4):

In OP's context, the only difference is that *could/would you [do something]?* is slightly more polite and/or "deferential" than *can/will you [do it]?*

The reason for this is simply *could/would* (and *might*) are verb forms more strongly associated with ***hypothetical scenarios***. So using them places more "distance" between the speaker and whatever he's asking for. There's more on the issue in [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5902/when-should-we-use-can-could-will-would) on ELU, and if you're prepared to read a bit more, have a look at this [excellent answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/21852/2637) to a closely-related question.

---

Re OP's point about *could* being a "past tense", I'd say that from some perspectives English doesn't really have a "past tense" anyway. What it has, particularly with [modal verbs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_verb) like *can, may, must, shall, will* is verb forms that often refer to the past, but can also refer to anything that's not *here, now, present*.

Thus if I say *"I **could** do it yesterday, and I **can** still do it today"*, *could* references *past time* (before the present) and *can* references the present. But if I say *"But I couldn't do it again without help"*, *could [not]* references either a *future* time (after the present), or a hypothetical time ("away" from the present), depending on how you want to look at it.

Answer (score 2):

*Could* can be more tentative, and may sometimes be more polite. However, the meaning depends on the context, the relationship between the participants in the conversation, and the speaker’s intonation.

Answer (score 0):

Because *could* is a form of *can*, the sensible differences between those requests come from tense/mood.

*Can* inquires about the present, definite future, or general ability/possibility:

- *Can you explain it (now)?*
- *Can you explain it (later, if I come to your office)?*
- *Can you explain it (under any set of circumstances)?*

*Could* indicates the subjunctive:

- *Could you explain it to me (if I were to specify the question)?*
- *Could you explain it to me (we were to find twenty minutes to talk)?*
- *Could you explain it to me (if you weren't doing something else right now)?*

If we mean to use can/could politely we're using them in pointed contrast to literal meaning: we're politely interested in convenience, preference, etc., and for that reason we do not ask about those things, and allow the conceit of ability to determine the outcome. And also asking after ability allows someone to issue a more definite "no" than asking after preference, convenience, whch is important.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please explain this to me?
Could you please explain this to me?

**Answer:**
Can is a rude way to ask, it's like giving a command.
Could is a polite way to ask, it's like a requesting.

For this case, "Could you please explain this to me"? is the suitable option.

Comment: This seems highly contextual. Where is "can" considered rude?