# What is the difference between "Could I have this... " and "Can I have this... "?

Tags: word-usage, difference, sentence-meaning, modal-verbs

I was thinking about the sentence "**Could** I Have This Kiss Forever" after listening the song "*Could I Have This Kiss Forever*" by Enrique Iglesias.

And I'm confused is this sentence gives a same meaning like "**Can** I Have This Kiss Forever". If not what is the difference between "**Could** I Have This Kiss Forever" and "**Can** I Have This Kiss Forever"?

*Someone may think this question as a duplicate one, but I didn't find answer for my question by another question.*
**Edit**: At most questions about Could/Can they give some idea about Could/Can but not about the meaning *difference* of the above sentences.

Comment: Can you tell us what part of [this answer](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/1459/18673) is not clear to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either could or can in the sentence, without any difference in meaning. The only difference is that could is more polite than can.