# "can" VS 'could"

Tags: modal-verbs

1. Although there are weeks of negotiations ahead, and perhaps setbacks and new surprises, leaders of both parties are optimistic that their differences **can** be resolved.
2. Although there are weeks of negotiations ahead, and perhaps setbacks and new surprises, leaders of both parties are optimistic that their differences **could** be resolved.

which modal verb is the most suitable here?

Comment: You need to use **are optimistic** / **can** and **were optimistic** / **could**. Only the first sentence uses one of those pairs—so it's the only one that's grammatical. (But if the second sentence *did* use **were optimistic**, then **could** would be fine, if a little awkward because of the use of **are weeks**.)

Comment: is this a duplicate https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1458/what-is-the-difference-between-can-and-could-in-can-could-you-please-explain-th